# How to create table under a schema in a database

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to create a database-table like sql, where we have database, under it schema then table under schema, so that fully qualified name of my table becomes database.schema.tablename.

I am seeing if something similar can be done in databricks for un-managed tables and if it is recommended approach.

I tried :create database mydb location" which created database, but not sure how to create schema under it. If i do "create schema myschema" it is showing as a new database in databricks UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark the *create database* syntax looks like this (see also the Databricks [documentation)](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-database.html#create-database):

```
CREATE (DATABASE|SCHEMA) [IF NOT EXISTS] db_name
  [COMMENT comment_text]
  [LOCATION path]
  [WITH DBPROPERTIES (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
```

As you can see there is no concept of a schema in a database. You can use *create schema* or *create database* to create a *schema* what in my opinion is the better term as you only create a schema definition. Data is stored in the defined *location*. You could have multiple table definitions pointing to the same *location* with un-managed tables.